# How to configure database permissions for a Django app?

Tags: database, django, security, permissions

I'm looking for links, or an answer here, on to how to properly configure the database permissions to secure a Django app?  To be clear, I'm looking specifically for material dealing with grants on the database, not permissions within the Django framework itself.

Answer (score 10):

From the django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/

> If you plan to use Django’s manage.py syncdb command to automatically create database tables for your models (after first installing Django and creating a project), you’ll need to ensure that Django has permission to create and alter tables in the database you’re using; if you plan to manually create the tables, you can simply grant Django SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE permissions. On some databases, Django will need ALTER TABLE privileges during syncdb but won’t issue ALTER TABLE statements on a table once syncdb has created it. After creating a database user with these permissions, you’ll specify the details in your project’s settings file, see DATABASES for details.

Answer (score 10):

I've just tested initial setup with MySQL. For `python manage.py migrate` at least you need following grants for simple operation (if yo use db-preparation):

1. CREATE, ALTER, INDEX
2. SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE

And, by the way - security matters. You can reduce attack impact by limiting your system exposure. In this case - you can restrict 'DROP' - which is fairly huge plus. If you leave some tricky hole with ability to SQL-inject - you probably reduce the damage. I will research in the future if it will not do any harm to remove DELETE keyword - that would limit potential threats as well. Just because we all leave bugs from time to time :)

Comment: GRANT CREATE, ALTER, INDEX, SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON django_db.* TO django_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'django_password';

Comment: Don't forget to grant REFERENCES apparently for MySQL 5.7+. Just ran into this for the first time today.

Comment: it would also be good to provide more than one database users that can access the same database table but with different set of privileges in your django project. For example, 2 database users are applied for the same table, one of them gets full-access permission and used for internal operations on your backend like backup / migration, the other one has minimal access privilege (e.g. ready-only, update-only ...etc) and used for handling frontend request.

Answer (score 8):

I usually:

```
grant all privileges on my_db.* to my_user@localhost identified by 'my_user_pass'
grant all privileges on test_my_db.* to my_user@localhost identified by 'my_user_pass'
```

I suppose if there were a bug in django, you might be opening your database up to terrible things, but you'd have other problems if there were that big of a security hole in django.

django minimally needs select, insert, update, and delete, to operate. If you're using test or syncdb at all, you'll also need to be able to create tables, and indexes (and maybe the file permission for loading sql fixtures).

So, for a mysql db, I'd guess the optimal set of permissions might be select, insert, update, delete, create, index, and file. If you wanted to get real nitty-gritty, you could selectively grant these permissions as appropriate on the table level (rather than the db level).

Personally, I find `grant all ...` easier to type.

Comment: Thanks Seth.  I do that too.  However, I was looking for the "real nitty-gritty" as you put it.   I saw something on the web a while back that covered this in detail and seemed like worthwhile hardening. Regrettably I didn't bookmark it...

Comment: This goes without saying, but after the above: `flush privileges;`

Comment: @mlissner Can you explain why?

Comment: @NatanYellin: No idea why it's necessary -- it's not in Postgres, for example. But in MySQL, it's just a thing you always have to do after you grant privileges.

Comment: In case anyone else attempts this, for MySQL the FILE permissions cannot be placed on a specific database, but must be global: http://preetul.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/1221-hy000-incorrect-usage-of-db-grant-and-global-privileges/

Comment: For syncdb the ALTER permission is also required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom migrations and use raw SQL for any fine-tuning. A simple example below.

---

1. First create an empty migration file

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations --empty myapp
```

2. Rename to something meaningful

```bash
mv 0002_* 0002_allow_workers_access_to_user_table.py
```

3. Edit your migration file

```py
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("myapp_user", "0001_initial"),
    ]

    operations = [

        # Allow web workers access to the user table
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql="""
                GRANT SELECT ON TABLE myapp_user TO "web-worker";
            """,
            reverse_sql="""
                REVOKE SELECT ON TABLE myapp_user FROM "web-worker";
            """,
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score -3):

What's the purpose of configuring permissions on DB level? If your server is compromised then the attacker will be able to do anything with your database (because he has the login/pass) and permissons won't help. If your server is secured then permissions are useless.

Permissions can make sense if your DB server is available from the outer world, but it is not a good idea to do so.

Comment: By adding DB permissions you have an opportunity to limit what can be achieved with an SQL injection etc attacks.  If the web server is compromised DB permissions have the potential to limit the damage - e.g. there likely isn't any reason for the web app login to be able to drop the database etc.

Comment: SQL injections are easy to avoid with django and I don't see a big difference between clearing all the tables and dropping the database. In either way you have your data lost and should restore anything from backup after eliminating the vulnerability. It is not obvious that DB-level permissions make your project more secure. I think that django doesn't have built-in support for DB-level permissions because it's better to put efforts in fixing real problems: XSS, CSRF, SQL injections, etc. and not to fool yourself with half measures.

Comment: Here's Microsoft's advice for ASP.NET apps "...Grant only the minimum permissions that the application must have to function."

And SANS "... The approach to this should be to grant only the minimum permissions the application requires to run."

Etc 

Flaws can be at any level in the application stack - why wouldn't you want to use every possible tool to prevent an attack propagating.

Comment: These are good advices. Running you web server with root permissions is a very bad idea indeed. Having separate unix and DB users for different sites on the same server is a great idea. In many cases this can help. But I don't see how grained DB-level permissions can help. If attacker is successful with something on lower level than django or on django level then he has at least the same permissions as django instance so he can trash the DB.

Comment: Or not if the django db connection has restricted rights.  BTW the two quotes above relate specifically to DB permissions for web apps.

Comment: Security comes in layers. Every layer can make a difference.